# Conditionally adding a check box in Telerik MVC Grid

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc, telerik-open-access

I am using Telerik Grid for MVC 3 with aspx engine. I have to add a check box only on those rows which status are completed.

```
 columns.Bound(grid => grid.CaseStatus).Width(80);
```

Above is my bound column now i have to check if CaseStatus value is some specific number then only i have to add check box with that row.

```
columns.Add(c => c.CaseID).Title("").Format("<input type='checkbox' />").Encoded(false).Width(5);
```

Any Idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [ClientTemplate](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/templatesclientside) to achieve this:

**Exmaple:**

```
columns.Bound(p => p.CaseStatus).Title("Case Status").ClientTemplate("<#= (CaseStatus==true) ? '<input type='checkbox' />' : '' #>");
```

Templates allow you to customise the way the data is presented in the grid and you can use `<#= #>` to embed and compare databound expressions in a similar way to server side templates.